# puppet exec vagrant plugin install not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos, provisioning, vagrant, puppet

I have successfully installed vagrant-aws on a centos VM, and I am trying to 'puppetize' this task. My relevant puppet code is below:

```
exec { 'install_aws':
  command => '/usr/bin/vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws',
  #require => [Exec['install_dependent'], Package['vagrant']],
}
```

When I provision the machine, it says the Exec[install_aws]/returns: executed successfully, but the plugin is not installed, and I have to run the command manually for it to work. Never seen this behaviour with puppet, can someone help?

Comment: When you run it manually, what user are you running it as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exec { 'install_aws':
  command => '/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws',
  require => [Exec['install_dependent'], Package['vagrant']],
}
```

Fixed the code above. Good point, needed to run the command as superuser. Seems like a silly mistake, thanks for pointing it out ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sudo` to run that command (as you pointed out in your answer), I would add the `user` paramater to the exec and run it as root (or any other user with suitable permissions)

```
exec { 'install_aws':
    user => 'root',
    command => '/usr/bin/vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws',
    require => [Exec['install_dependent'], Package['vagrant']],
}
```